# Convert class with references to other classes to dict in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

My goal is to convert a class to a dict, recursively. I understand that I need to specify the rules related to the conversion, but I feel like there is some way for built-in python to recurse the class and produce a dict. See the following code:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
    self.b = 2
    self.c = 3

  def __iter__(self):
    yield 'a', self.a
    yield 'b', self.b
    yield 'c', self.c


class Bar:
  def __init__(self, foos):
    self.foos = foos
    self.d = 5

  def __iter__(self):
    yield 'foos', self.foos
    yield 'd', self.d

foos = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]

bar = Bar(foos)

print(dict(bar))
```

The result of this is:
`{'foos': [<__main__.Foo object at 0x108e6be48>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x108e6bef0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x108e6bf28>], 'd': 5}`

`foos` in this case is a list of `Foo()`s, which I would hope to see an expanded list of dicts. I know I can add the following to the `Foo` class to make this work:

```
def __repr__(self):
  return repr(dict(self))
```

Results in the desired output:
`{'foos': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}], 'd': 5}`

but that approach seems hacky - as in, I'm forcing it to represent itself as a dict, rather than naturally iterable (which feels like I'm trying to put a square peg in a round hole).

My question to the python world is: what is the proper way to approach this so that I can call dict() on my class and get a full dictionary?

*I've searched around and can't seem to find anything specific to this topic so I'm going to ask here. If this already exists please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for your help!*

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with two hacks that can fill your needs.

**1st: Exposing dicts in `foos` variable by replacing this line:**

```
foos = [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]
```

by this kind of hacks using `list comprehension`:

```
foos =[dict(k) for k in [Foo(), Foo(), Foo()]]
```

Or, simply like this:

```
foos = [dict(Foo()), dict(Foo()), dict(Foo())]
```

then:

```
print(dict(bar))
>>> {'d': 5, 'foos': [{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}]}
```

**2nd: Exposing dicts inside `Bar.__iter__()` by replacing this line:**

```
yield 'foos', self.foos
```

by:

```
yield [dict(k) for k in self.foos]
```

Then:

```
print(dict(bar))
>>> {'d': 5, 'foos': [{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}]}
```

**Bonus (not exactly what you want): Using `dict comprehension` by replacing this line:**

```
print(dict(bar))
```

by:

```
print({k:v if isinstance(v, int) else [dict(j) for j in v] for k,v in dict(bar).items()})
```

which will print:

```
>>> {'d': 5, 'foos': [{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - those will work, but they're forcing the dict into the equation, which is similar to what I already did. I guess what I'm specifically looking for is to avoid hacking it in by forcing the dict explicitly. If that isn't possible via python, then I guess I'll take that approach. The dict comprehension is also interesting - thanks for that!

Comment: Well i'll try to improve more my answer, otherwise you can try which one fills your need and use it.